# How do I send mouse and keyboard events to another process?

Tags: c#, windows, events

Let's assume that we've got 2 windows processes ,

Process A is the sender, and Process B is the receiver.

Process B is running a classic Win32 API events loop

How do I generate and send mouse and keyboard events from process A to B ?

Comment: Sounds like you're making a bot.

Comment: What's wrong with making a bot, @Droo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically via `SendMessage` or `PostMessage`. If you want to simulate input events for the whole operating system, then `SendInput` might be interesting.

Comment: might I ask for a short example?

Comment: SendMessage/PostMessage will not work correctly with keyboard. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check TestAPI in Codeplex it includes some C# classes that wrap SendMessage and PostMessage APIs (http://testapi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/35517#424245)

Answer (score 1):

TestApi actually wraps up SendInput internally, and exposes a couple of simple classes -- **Mouse** and **Keyboard** -- to help you simulate input. SendInput provides the most general way to inject input, but is a notoriously tricky API to use -- the wrappers simplify the usage greatly.

See [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ivo_manolov/introduction-to-testapi-part-1-input-injection-apis) for specific usage examples.