# send mouse click to winamp

Tags: c#, winapi, winamp

I'm trying to learn mouse/keyboard emulation using win api.
I found out that it is possible to emulate button click using sendmessage() function.

Well, I get coordinates of "play" button (it is (60;100)) and trying to push this button using the following code:

```
            int x = 60;
            int y = 100;
            int lParam = ((x << 16) | (y & 0xffff));

            int parentWindow = FindWindow("BaseWindow_RootWnd", "Main Window");//get main winamp window
            MessageBox.Show(parentWindow.ToString());//failed if 0

            SendMessage(parentWindow, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(lParam));//send left mouse button down
            SendMessage(parentWindow, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(lParam));//send left mouse button up
```

But this code has no effect on the winamp.

Can anybody point me on the mistakes i made? Any help is greatly appreciated!

p.s. It's not applicable for me to move mouse to the winamp play button, than do a click, than move it back.
Also for winamp it is impossible to get button's handle. With button handle SendMessage() works fairly well, but with coordinates it doesn't at all.

***ADDITION #1***

Well, the code above activates winamp window and shows it, if it was minimized. But play button stil don't want to be pushed ;(

***ADDITION #2***

Here are messages I get after I execute the code above.

[image: Messages in spy++]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4957386/402169. Mouse input is the same as keyboard input in this context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send mouse and keyboard events to another process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655082/how-do-i-send-mouse-and-keyboard-events-to-another-process)

Comment: Why not use the UIAutomation namespace? That's what it's for.

Comment: @Deanna, I solved it by myself, just forgot to mark it as an answer, thanks for reminding me. If interested - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, to simulate mouse click in winamp window you need to do exactly what is happening when you just click it with hardware mouse. The following was found out from spy++:
[image]

So to emulate mouse click we need to:

1. Call twice `PostMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()` because **"P"** in the screenshot above tells us that the message was got from the PostMessage() (according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470399))
2. The parameters should be the following for the first PostMessage():
        - First parameter - Winamp window handle (in our case it is `005E09FA`)
        - Second parameter - the winapi code of the event, when left mouse button is down(`WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201`)
        - Third parameter - `MK_LBUTTON = 0x1` (It seems, it is necessary to pass it. It would be great if somebody can explain why)
        - Fourth parameter - Coordinates of the point where you want to press mouse button (this parameter can be calculated as following - `((Y << 16) | X)`)
3. The parameters should be the following for the second PostMessage():
        - First parameter - Winamp window handle (in our case it is `005E09FA`)
        - Second parameter - the winapi code of the event, when left mouse button is up (`WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202`)
        - Third parameter - `0` or `IntPtr.Zero`
        - Fourth parameter - Coordinates of the point where you want to release mouse button (need to be as in first PostMessage() if you want your click to have an effect; this parameter can be calculated as following - `((Y << 16) | X)`)

Thanks everyone for their input!

Answer (score 2):

To let Winamp play/pause the current song, simply send it a Play/Pause message, which is long 40046 as defined in `winamp.h`. You'll have to send it in a `WM_WA_IPC` message (which is a user message, also known as `WM_USER`) instead of a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.

So, something like this should do:

```
SendMessage(parentWindow, WM_USER, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(40046));
```

More info [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=35586), [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=302649) and [here](http://www.koders.com/c/fid556E7D2B6434BB0911EFD08136492531E8FBED47.aspx).

Comment: it's great, but my initial intention was to understand how can mouse/keyboard can be emulated. Thank you, though.

Comment: @mr.nothing if it is for learning purposes, why don't you write your own test program that emits all Windows messages it receives? You could also achieve this using `Spy++`.

Comment: well, I using spy++ already, and when I execute code provided above spy++ detects some strange messages, but they are not WM_LBUTTONDOWN or WM_LBUTTONUP or something like that. Please, see updated topic (screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`SendInput()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+sendinput) to send input to other applications, not faking window messages.

Comment: well, I tried it and as I thought it is impossible to make a click without moving mouse cursor. I need to simulate mouse click without moving it.

Comment: If you simulate only part of mouse input behavior, you're not really simulating it. It's nonsensical to have the mouse click in a place where the cursor is not.

Comment: @tenfour, well if we are talking about testing purposes, than it really do have a sense to make a click in a place where the cursor is not, because it allows you to do anything else, when your tests being performed.

Comment: No, it's not a complete simulation then. You cannot have your cake and eat it too. Maybe you should put it in a VM?

Comment: @tenfour, well, maybe there are some hidden pitfalls which i'm not aware of, but it seems that it works for me. Please, see my answer.

Comment: As you said in another comment, you're interested in a generalize solution. This is a solution that only works in one specific application; others will fail you. For example you haven't bothered to simulate `GetKeyState`, or deal with the mouse coords in the `MSG` structure. Any application relying on these will fail (which is very common).

Comment: @tenfour, yes, you're right about generalization. Could you provide any application as an example, where approach I suggested is not working so I can investigate it?